# Ionic V1 - Print special characters in ion-radio

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button, html-escape-characters, ionic-v1

In my controller, I am generating template dynamically with the REST API response and then showing the values as ion-radio.

**My Code**

```
var generatedTemplate = '<ion-list>';

angular.forEach($scope.longPressOptions, function(value, index) {
  generatedTemplate += '<ion-radio class="item-text-wrap" ng-model="longPressOptions.selectedValue" ng-value="' + value.wc_id + '">' + value.wc_name + '</ion-radio>';
}

generatedTemplate +=  '</ion-list>';
```

The **value.wc_name** may contain **"<Default>", "N/A", ...** values. These kind of values are not listed and shows error.

How to print the values as it is, without converting it to HTML format?

**EDIT 1:** (Image added)

**<Default>** should be displayed in the highlighted area.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** (Generated code)

```
<h5 style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray">Bystar 3015-2</h5> 
<ion-list>
  <ion-radio class="item-text-wrap" ng-model="longPressOptions.scheduleSelectedWC" ng-value="2"> //NewName 
  </ion-radio>
  <ion-radio class="item-text-wrap" ng-model="longPressOptions.scheduleSelectedWC" ng-value="10">N/A 
  </ion-radio>
  <ion-radio class="item-text-wrap" ng-model="longPressOptions.scheduleSelectedWC" ng-value="11"><Default> 
  </ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: shows error means which error?

Comment: @PareshGami the value <Default> is being considered as HTML. I think so. But all I wanted is to print the value as it is. The value can be any character. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can print  as string in html like

```
 <ion-radio class="item-text-wrap" ng-model="longPressOptions.scheduleSelectedWC" ng-value="11"> <![CDATA[ <default> ]]>
  </ion-radio>
```

Comment: After making the code as ### "generatedTemplate += '<ion-radio class="item-text-wrap" ng-model="longPressOptions.scheduleSelectedWC" ng-value="' + value.wc_id + '">' + '<![CDATA[' + value.wc_name + ']]>' + ' </ion-radio>';" ### the text for other radio button becomes empty.

Comment: You have to use ng-repeat for display dynamic radio generation

Comment: I checked. But the same behavior as mentioned in previous comment. :(

Comment: Use ng-repeat for $scope.longPressOptions

Comment: It seems ng-repeat does not work in ionic popup. I will check and update soon. Thanks for your timely reply. Link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/list-in-a-pop-up-using-ng-repeat-for-list-items/7616